# progressBar with 5 checkbox

Tags: java, android-studio, checkbox

I need progressBar to load the percentage of how many checkboxes are checked.

I tried to use it for 5 checkbox:

"progressbar.setProgress (20)" if it was checked, and if it was not "progressbar.setProgress (-20)"

The progressBar loads only "20%" even if the 5 checkboxes are checked.Can someone help me?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    final CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    final CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    final CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);


    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    if (preferences.contains("checkbox1") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox1", false) == true) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", true);
                progressBar.setProgress(20);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", false);
                progressBar.setProgress(-20);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });


    if (preferences.contains("checkbox2") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox2", false) == true) {
        checkBox2.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox2.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", true);
                progressBar.setProgress(20);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", false);
                progressBar.setProgress(-20);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });


    if (preferences.contains("checkbox3") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox3", false) == true) {
        checkBox3.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox3.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox3", true);
                progressBar.setProgress(20);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox3", false);
                progressBar.setProgress(-20);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

    if (preferences.contains("checkbox4") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox4", false) == true) {
        checkBox4.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox4.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox4", true);
                progressBar.setProgress(20);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox4", false);
                progressBar.setProgress(-20);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

    if (preferences.contains("checkbox5") && preferences.getBoolean("checkbox5", false) == true) {
        checkBox5.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox5.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox5", true);
                progressBar.setProgress(20);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox5", false);
                progressBar.setProgress(-20);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions are most likely to receive good help when they're clear and specific, and contain a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post some of the actual code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Ready. Thank you @bnaecker :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you always set it to 20 or -20 instead of updating it from its current value. use

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+20);
```

or

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()-20);
```